# Factorials of Big numbers without BigInteger (C#)

Tags: c#, algorithm, math, factorial

Is there an algorithm for calculating a factorial without using `System.Numerics` library? We receive an `int` number and we need to return factorial of this number as `string`(if n = 30, we should return "265252859812191058636308480000000", if n = 70, we should return "11978571669969891796072783721689098736458938142546425857555362864628009582789845319680000000000000000" ect. Numbers are very big)

I tried to find out, did anyone already write an article about that, but I didn't find anything.

Comment: What is the problem, then? You should work with strings, i.e. you have to implement string *addition* (`Add("123", "456") == "579"`) and *multiplication*: `Mul("123", "456") == "56088"`. Where have you stuck? All you have to do is to mimic good all school algorithms of addition and multiplication.

Comment: Sure. Just write your own BigInteger library. The problem you are facing is that any factorial above 20 will result in an integer overflow. Meaning the 64bits that are used to represent the number stored in an int flips over. Think of it as adding 1 to the number number 15 represented as 4bits. 1111 + 0001. It would overflow and you'd end with 0000. Same problem - which is why you need a BigInteger.

Comment: _"Is there an algorithm for calculating a factorial"_ - Well, yes. But I guess you know how to multiply. Now you "just" need to figure out how to represent and perform multiplication on numbers that exceed the `int` (and `long`) range.

Comment: The numbers get so big so fast that you mustn't have such a huge range of inputs. Just pre-calculate the strings for the first 1000 say factorials and use them as a look-up table.

Comment: You can just use big integer - it has virtually no limit: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.numerics.biginteger?view=net-7.0

Answer (score 2):

It suffices to implement multiplication of a large number as a string by a small integer.

Illustration: `12! = 11! x 12` is obtained by multiplying every digit by `12` and summing (with shifts):

```
 39916800
36
108
 108
   12
    72
     96
       0
        0
---------
479001600
```

Answer (score 0):

**A lazy solution**. It is possible to evaluate the factorial with just BigNum addition, replacing the multiplications by successive additions. (For `n!`, we will perform `1+2+3+...n-1` additions. This is acceptable for moderate `n`.)

The computation uses two pre-allocated string (arrays of char), which are initially filled with null bytes (Writeline skips them). When adding from right to left, we stop when we meet a null.

```
int n = 20;

// Factorial and temporary string; 100! fits in 158 digits
const int N = 158;
char[] f = new char[N], t = new char[N];
f[N - 1] = '1'; // 1!

// Product up to n by successive additions
for (int i = 2; i <= n; i++)
{
    // t= f
    f.CopyTo(t, 0);
    for (int j = 0; j < i - 1; j++)
    {
        // f+= t, repeated i-1 times
        int c = 0; // Carry
        for (int k = N - 1; k >= 0; k--)
        {
            if (t[k] == 0 && c == 0) break; // Significant part exhausted
            int d = Math.Max(0, t[k] - '0') + Math.Max(0, f[k] - '0') + c;
            c= d / 10; d = d % 10; f[k] = (char)(d + '0'); // Next carry/digit
        }
    }
    Console.WriteLine(f);
}
```

Output:

```
2
6
24
120
720
5040
40320
362880
3628800
39916800
479001600
6227020800
87178291200
1307674368000
20922789888000
355687428096000
6402373705728000
121645100408832000
2432902008176640000
```

Answer (score -1):

```
static string FindFactorial(int n)
    {
        int[] result = new int[500000];
        result[0] = 1;
        int resultSize = 1;

        for (int x = 2; x <= n; x++)
            resultSize = Multiply(x, result, resultSize);

        string factorial = "";
        for (int i = resultSize - 1; i >= 0; i--)
            factorial += result[i].ToString();

        return factorial;
    }

    static int Multiply(int x, int[] result, int resultSize)
    {
        int carry = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < resultSize; i++)
        {
            int product = result[i] * x + carry;
            result[i] = product % 10;
            carry = product / 10;
        }

        while (carry != 0)
        {
            result[resultSize] = carry % 10;
            carry /= 10;
            resultSize++;
        }

        return resultSize;
    }
```

This will work

Comment: int[] result = new int[500000];  result max size